# Which scientist(s) first measured the elementary charge and how did they do it?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electricity, physicists

I would be grateful if anyone could shed some light on these questions.

1. Which scientist(s) first measured the elementary charge? If it wasn't measured in a straightforward experimental setting, and was posited a priori or derived from some prior equation formally, what was the underlying reasoning?
2. What experiment or a set of experiments led to the empirical confirmation of the value of the elementary charge?

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question, even if [Is Millikan's famous oil drop experiment a fraud?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2756/is-millikans-famous-oil-drop-experiment-a-fraud) discusses Milikan experiment it does not answer the question directly. Particularly, the answers there state that Milikan was a fraud, so who measured it first?

Comment: @Mauricio precisely, I don't understand why the question was closed. And the wiki doesn't mention the history of its discovery and experimental measurement. The other question about Millikan concerns a different subject altogether. It skirts past the question of which experiment was the first to settle the matter in a definitive way.